# proprietory drives for ubuntu 12.04 intel 3000 hd graphics

Tags: graphics, intel

I am trying find out if you can install updated drivers for Intel 3000 HD graphic card. I'm been hearing Intel graphics don't really have proprirtory drivers and they are open source versions. Then, how can I improve my graphics with my current graphics card?

Comment: Yes, they are open-source and are included in the Kernel. *Then, how can I improve my graphics with my current graphics card?* - What do you mean by improve?

Comment: How can I improve my performance with my current video graphics?

Answer (score 0):

**I really recommend you stick with the default driver that comes with the kernel.**

If you feel adventurous, you can install the latest drivers from [the edgers ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers).

*This is really experimental and you should only use it if you know how to recover from a broken graphics driver.*

first install ppa-purge in case something goes wrong

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

add the xorg-edgers ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

refresh package list and switch to new driver

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

reboot

If this messes up your system and you want to revert back to the offical driver run:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

If you are greeted with a completely unusable display press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> I always forget which one, to open a console and run the ppa-purge command.

*"This is an environment of welcoming... so you should just... get the hell out of here" --Michael Scott*

Comment: Or what about [ppa:glasen/intel-driver](https://launchpad.net/~glasen/+archive/intel-driver) for a bit less adventurous but considerably newer than the defult one(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Now you can get intel graphics from their [open source site](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intel-linux-graphics-installer) which has instruction on installation there. Once you have run the software it is advised you use synaptics or apt-get for updates.